# Add custom folder programatically to Document Library

Tags: development, document-library, visual-studio, content-type

I have a custom Document Library that has a custom content type which is an extension of a Folder (just adding some more fields). I'm trying to, in code, add a new item of this content type to the library. But I get the error:

> To add an item to a document library, use SPFileCollection.Add()

But what I am adding is not a file, and all the overloads for that method require some kind of file stream or object. I've tried:

```
SPListItem newCustomFolder = docLibrary.Folders.Add();
SPListItem newCustomFolder = docLibrary.AddItem();
SPListItem newCustomFolder = docLibrary.Items.Add();
```

And trying to declare it as SPFolder doesn't match the return of the above functions nor does accept setting fields.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had an idea, and creating it as a folder, then getting the item representation of that folder, and then changing that items content type and setting all the custom fields seems to have worked.

```
SPFolderCollection folders = docLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders;
SPFolder newFolder = folders.Add(SALAE_docLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/foo");
SPListItem newCustomFolder = newFolder.Item;
//set content type, set fields
```